# How to use Google translate api to translate specific word only

Tags: transactions, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I want to translate specific word only in my PHP website.

for example

```
    Data      Language      Translation
---------------------------------------------
    Hello     select        ___________
```

When user select language from drop down than Translation field should be update with translation of Hello into selected language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gtranslate-api-php](https://code.google.com/p/gtranslate-api-php/), its pretty simple to use it.

```
<?php
      require("GTranslate.php");

      try{
         $gt = new Gtranslate;
         echo "Translating [Hello World] from English to German => ".$gt->english_to_german("hello world")."<br/>";
         echo "Translating [Ciao mondo] Italian to English => ".$gt->it_to_en("Ciao mondo")."<br/>";
      } catch (GTranslateException $ge)
      {
        echo $ge->getMessage();
      }
?>
```

BTW, you should make a ajax request when users selects the lang to a php file(if you are not using a framework) which contains this code and than return the value and populate the required field.